# Multiple column SUMS with single formula

Tags: google-sheets, sum, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to `SUM` multiple columns (sum for each column, not a total range sum) with a single formula.  So the output would look something like this:

```
+-------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+
| 2019  | 2018  |    2017    |   2016    |    2015    |
+-------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+
| $0.00 | $0.00 | $4,341.00  | $0.00     | $5,281.00  |
| $0.00 | 0     | 0          | 0         | 0          |
| $0.00 | 0     | $10,805.00 | $2,865.00 | $8,295.00  |
| $0.00 | 0     | 0          | 0         | $233.00    |
+-------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+
| $0.00 | $0.00 | $15,146.00 | $2,865.00 | $13,809.00 |
+-------+-------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

I've tried several approaches (`SUM`,`SUMIF`,`SUMIFS`,`MMULT`), but can't seem to get it right.  The closest I've come is with this formula from a website I found

`=ArrayFormula(MMULT(B2:F5,(transpose(COLUMN(B1:F1)^0))))`

I would also prefer to avoid the need for a 0 value as shown in the `MMULT` attempt below.  But, if that's what it takes to make it work, so be it.  But a blank value would be preferred.  Am I attempting the impossible or just looking in the exact wrong direction?

[My sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18b6mzFnSRdng9uyirEf-LJcm6_d72WgyWSsuEQOWqIE/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:5<>"", B2:5, 0)), ROW(B2:5)^0)))
```

[image: 0]